# Springboot+Hibernate Relationship question

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, relation

I've been looking for the answer to the question for 2 days now, but i can't describe the question well. That's why I can't find the answer...

I have 3 entities User, Patient, Address.

Both user and patient contain a list of addresses.

How to annotate the models now, so that there is only one address table. In my solutions I have to use a OneToMany annotation but in the address entity I have to connect both the user and the patient.

I hope you could understand my problem.

My current Models:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient extends Base {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Base {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-unidirectional

Answer (score 0):

You may want to specify the @OneToMany association using a @JoinTable annotation (one cross reference table for each type of association, rather than a @JoinColumn in the Adress table) to the Adress table. More info here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-one-to-many-with-join-table

You would end up with something like:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient extends Base {

...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="PATIENT_ADDRESSES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="PATIENT_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="ADDRESS_ID")
    )
    public Set<Address> getAddressess() { return addresses; }
}
```

Then you would something similar with your user table using a USER_ADDRESSES join table